# Unable to use django-extensions commands

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django, django-extensions

I have created an app and project using django_cookie_cutter. I can run admin_generator, reset_db, makemigrations, migrate. show_urls is not listed in the subcommands. dumpdata is and I cannot use dumpdata.

```
Python==3.9
Django==3.2.13
django-extensions==3.1.5

pip3 install django-extensions
```

Added to INSTALLED_APPS django_extensions and my app

```
>>> import django_extensions
>>> django_extensions.VERSION
(3, 1, 5)


manage.py


Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runserver
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver
```

The output for django.conf.settings.INSTALLED_APPS. It doesn't look like django_extensions is added to INSTALLED_APPS

```
./manage.py shell
In [2]: import django
In [5]: django.conf.settings.INSTALLED_APPS
Out[5]: []
```

Comment: I know you say you have, but it sounds like `django_extensions` isn't in `INSTALLED_APPS`...

Comment: I was able to get django_extensions to appear in my project after playing around with the settings.